# How can I analyze the relationship between a quantitative and a categorical variable in a within-subject design?

Tags: logistic, correlation, repeated-measures, spss, binary-data

For my bachelor thesis I'm conducting a study on the relationship between eye-movements and memory. One of the hypotheses is that the number of fixations made during the viewing of a movie clip will be positively related to the memory that clip.

Each participant viewed 100 movie clips, and the number of fixations were counted for each movie clip for each participant. Later, participants' memory of the clips were tested and each movie was categorized as "remembered" or "forgotten" for each participant.
So, for each participants there are 100 trials with the corresponding number of fixations and categorization as "remembered" or "forgotten".

My first idea was to do a paired-samples t-test (to compare the number of fixations between "remembered" and "forgotten"), but I didn't find a way to do that in SPSS with this file format as there are 100 rows for each participant. I though of calculating the average number of fixations for the remembered vs forgotten movies per participant and compare and do a t-test on these means (one mean per participant for both categories) but this way the means get distorted because some subjects remember way more clips than others (so the "mean of the means" is not the same as the overall mean).

Now I'm thinking that doing a t-test might not be appropriate at all, and that logistic regression would be a better choice (to see how well the number of fixations predicts whether a clip will be remembered vs forgotten), but I didn't manage to find out how to do this in SPSS in for a within subject design with multiple trials per participant. Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

| Subject ID | Remembered (0-no, 1-yes) | number of fixations | number of details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 14 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 13 |  |